# Flexbox styling - trying to center Views

Tags: html, css, react-native, flexbox

I am building a React Native application, and I am having a horrible time centering everything. Everything is always slightly off center:

```
  <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  }}>
    <View styleName="green-header">
      <Text styleName="green-header-text">Log In to Your Account</Text>
    </View>
    <View styleName="loginbuttongroup">
      <TouchableOpacity styleName="googlered loginbutton" onPress={() => this.onGoogleLoginButtonPress()}>
        <Text styleName="login-text">Log In with Google</Text>
        <Image styleName="login-img" sourcec={GoogleImg} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity styleName="facebookblue loginbutton"
        self={this} onPress={() => this.onFBLoginButtonPress()}>
        <Text styleName="login-text">Log In with Facebook</Text>
        <Image styleName="login-img" source={FBImg} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity styleName="bottomtext">
      <Link to="/signup/">
        <View styleName="bottomtext-text-view"><Text styleName="bottomtext-text">Don't have an account? Sign Up</Text></View>
      </Link>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

I am using a module that allows me to write styles like CSS (this is what the styleName attributes above are applying):

```
.green-header {

  height: 40;
  width: 400;
  margin-top: 20;
  align-items: center;
}
.green-header-text {
  height: 40;
  width: 200;
  color: #31bdbc;
  font-size: 16;
}
.login-text {
  color: #fff;
}
.facebookblue {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
}
.googlered {
  background-color: #db3236;
  color: #fff;
}
.loginbutton {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.loginbuttongroup {
  height: 400;
  width: 40%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.login-img {
  width: 20;
  height: 20;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.bottomtext {
  width: 300;
  height: 300;
align-self: flex-end;
}
.bottom-text-text-view {
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
}
.bottomtext-text {

  color: #31bdbc;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Now based on this, I would expect that my loginbuttongroup is vertically centered, and each of my loginbuttons is 80% of the width of the container (which is set to 40% - if I make it any larger, the buttons go off the screen). Along with this, I'd expect bottomtext to be at the bottom. It doesn't even show up.

What am I misunderstanding about flexbox here? I just picked it up two weeks ago and I'm having a hell of a time getting it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the outermost view to `Justify-content: center` and all the buttons to `margin: auto`. If the positioning is off, sometimes it's because the margins are aligning incorrectly from an inherited bit of css.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the container `justify-content: center` not the element in the container

Comment: can you do it in code pen so i can help you on code?